# ACF field not updated

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I created an ACF field Text named 'user-dir' linked to the table 'users'.

- 'User Role' is equal to 'All'
- 'User Form' is equal to 'Add/Edit'

Normally, the ACF field is updated when user registers. That does not.

The belowed code must:

- create a directory with user_id => that works fine, the directory is created
- set the value of the ACF field 'user-dir' to 'bla bla bla' => that does not work and the ACF field 'user-dir' is not updated.

Could you help me please to understand what is wrong.

```
function create_user_dir($user_id) {
   $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
   wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $user_id );
   $userdir = 'bla bla bla';
   update_field( 'user-dir', $userdir, $user_id );
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'create_user_dir');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the field - but on the wrong object.

See https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/#update-a-value-from-different-objects - to update an ACF value on a *user*, you need to prefix the user id with `user_`,

```
$post_id = "user_2"; // user ID = 2
```

So in your above code, this should be

```
update_field( 'user-dir', $userdir, 'user_' . $user_id );
```